# Dart dependency injection of a class with parameters

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection

I am trying to learn about dependency injection and trying to use it in `Flutter/Dart`. I have gone through the library `get_it` which I find very useful.

But I am having a doubt about the dependency injection in a specific situation.

If I have a Dart class with parameters like this one for example:

```
class MyClass(){
    final String name;

    MyClass({this.name})

    ....
    ....
}
```

In such a class, with parameters, It seems like I cannot use dependency injection? or at least the following using `get_it` will not work:

**** service_locator.dart ****

```
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';

GetIt locator = GetIt();

void setupLocator() {
  locator.registerLazySingleton<MyClass>(() => MyClass());
}
```

This gives error on `=> MyClass()`....since it is expecting a parameter.

How to do this kind of injection?.

Answer (score 3):

You just pass the argument you want to `MyClass()`. You don’t have to do it inside `setUpLocator()`. Register the singleton, anywhere in your program, when you know what argument to pass.

For example, if you need to register a user object as a singleton, you’ll have to do it after the user logs in and all their info is available in order to properly instantiate your `User` class.

Answer (score 2):

because it is a singleton you only need to call `myClass.name = 'name'` once, anywhere in your app and it will change everywhere.
example app:

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    GetIt.instance.registerLazySingleton<MyClass>(()=> MyClass());

    // Name from a future
    get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then((response){
      if(response.statusCode==200) {
        setState(() {
          GetIt.I.get<MyClass>().name = jsonDecode(response.body)[0]['name'];
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Title'),
    ),
    body: Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text(GetIt.I.get<MyClass>().name),
      ),
    ),
    );
  }
}

class MyClass{
  String name = '';
}
```

*another way is that because it's built using a lazy builder, the MyClass object will only be built after the first `locator.get<MyClass>()` is called so you can prepare and get it from a static variable.*

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue passing a string into the constructor of your class. You only need access to the value you want to pass into the `MyClass` constructor. One way to do that is to get the value from another dependency. In this example, you can grab it from `AppOptions`.

```dart
import 'package:ioc_container/ioc_container.dart';

class MyClass {
  final String name;

  MyClass({required this.name});
}

class AppOptions {
  String get myClassName => 'Bob';
}

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  final builder = IocContainerBuilder()
    ..addSingletonService<AppOptions>(AppOptions())
    ..addSingleton(
        (container) => MyClass(name: container<AppOptions>().myClassName));

  final container = builder.toContainer();

  final myClass = container<MyClass>();

  print(myClass.name);
}
```

Grab the package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/ioc_container)

This prints

> Bob

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a default param for you MyClass class like this :

```
void setupLocator() {
  locator.registerLazySingleton<MyClass>(() => MyClass("Default Name"));
}
```

When requestion an instance of MyClass you default param ("Default Name") will be override by that instance param.
Hope you understand ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use registerFactoryParam

With one parameter:

```
MyClass({
  super.key,
  this.color,
  });
 Color color;
}
```

Register

```
  GetIt.instance.registerFactoryParam<MyClass, Color, void>(
      (c, _) => MyClass(color: c));
```

Use:

```
final myColor= GetIt.instance<IProgessIndicator>(param1: Colors.white);
```